# HostGator, Laravel and Email

Tags: laravel, email

I am configuring my Laravel app to send a welcome email, just like Jeffrey Way said at Laracasts and it works fine in Mailtrap. But when I change to HostGator, which I will use in real world, it just not work at all!

Here's some code:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=srv218.prodns.com.br
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=automatico@cepcar.com.br
MAIL_PASSWORD=******* <- obviously hidden
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Have changed the driver to SMTP, encryption to SSL, none but got no success. And the problem is that there are NO ERRORS to debug!

Comment: Do you mean to use the smtp driver?

Comment: Have you actually set the email address up host side?

Comment: @Devon
Yes, I meant!

Comment: @Option,
Yes, I configured exactly how it is instructed.

Answer (score 6):

The following changes should solve your issue.

1. Set a mail from address which is same as MAIL_USERNAME.
2. Change your mail driver to smtp.
3. Change mail encryption to ssl.

   ```
   MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
   MAIL_HOST=srv218.prodns.com.br
   MAIL_PORT=465
   MAIL_USERNAME=automatico@cepcar.com.br
   MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
   MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
   MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=automatico@cepcar.com.br
   ```

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is to make the following configuration in the **.env** file in hostgator to be able to send the emails with the corporate emails you have to define your domain on the host

MAIL_HOST= mail.**<tu_dominio>** => mail.amazonventas.com

MAIL_PORT=465  => estatico

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.amazonventas.com 
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=**********@amazonventas.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="*********"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=********@amazonventas.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
```